# BIT 0 represented as '\x00'

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pymysql, sqlacodegen

In a database table I have a column defined as:
[image]

Using this query:
    query = text(
            "SELECT * FROM `%s` WHERE " % "aTable"
            "%s=%s AND " % ("done", 0) 
            )

```
    result = engine.execute(query)
    row = result.fetchone()
```

when I call **print row['done']** then I get **'\x00'**.

For generation of tables I **sqlacodegen** which generated the **done** columns as this:

```
Column('done', BIT(1), nullable=False),
```

Am I missing some configuration in SqlAlchemy? I don't want to convert the hex to int everywhere I am goint to use a BIT column.

**EDIT**
So the problem is not with sqlalchemy but it seems that pymysql is to blame.

Answer (score 3):

Try to have a look to this chapter of the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/struct.html).

However, in your case, it might be enough something like **[ord](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#ord)** to convert your hex:

```
>>> a = b'\x00' 
>>> a
'\x00'
>>> str(a)
'\x00'
>>> ord(a)
0
>>> ord('\x5f')
95
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to override the BIT column converter and pass it to connection of pyMysql:

```
from pymysql import converters
converions = converters.conversions
converions[FIELD_TYPE.BIT] = lambda x: False if '\x00' else True
return pymysql.connect(
        conv=converions,
        ...
    )
```